Implement connection-pooling in ktor/exposed
I am new to ktor and exposed!
I setup a ktor server which has access to a postgres database. For accessing the data exposed should be used. Now if I use the database Object from exposed, there is no connection-pooling by default. Which framework or approach should be choosen with ktor and exposed. My first idea was to use hikaricp. I don't know if this is right.
fun Application.configureDatabases(): Database {
    return connectToPostgres(embedded = true)
}

fun Application.connectToPostgres(embedded: Boolean): Database {
    return Database.connect(
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1",
        user = "root",
        password = ""
    )
}

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(CIO, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0", module = Application::module)
        .start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.module() {
    val database = configureDatabases()
    configureDependencyInjection(database) // passing the Database object to 
    configureSerialization()
    configureRouting()
}

The ktor documentation for caching and data pooling is a redirect to: https://ktor.io/docs/server-integrate-database.html, but there is no documentation on data-pooling :-(
I tried hikaricp:
val hikariConfig = HikariConfig().apply {
        driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
        jdbcUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
        maximumPoolSize = 10
    }

    val dataSource = HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)

    return Database.connect(dataSource)

